# Bootstrap collapse with wrong behavior

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

My problem is that I have 2 blocks in modal and when I click on `.emailInbound` checkbox it toggle `.in-serv-container` open, but when I click on `.accordion-heading` to open comment part it makes `.in-serv-container collapse`.
What can be a reason?

HTML:

```
    <label class="checkbox">
        <input class="emailInbound" type="checkbox" onclick="toggleInServ(this)">Использовать Email для регистрации обращений
    </label>
    <div id='in-serv-container'>
        <div><strong>Настройка входящей почты</strong></div>
        <div>
            <input class="emailOutserver" type="text" placeholder="Сервер входящей почты">
            <input class="emailOutserverPort" type="text" placeholder="Порт">
        </div>
        <div>
            <select class="emailOutProtocol half" style="width: 49%!important;">
                <option value='usual'>Обычный</option>
                <option value='ssl'>SSL</option>
            </select>
            <input class="emailInFolder half" type="text" placeholder="Папка входящей почты">
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body-container">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Опции">
        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-link">Проверить подключение</button>
        <hr>
    </div>
    <div class="accordion" id="comment-wrapper">
        <div class="accordion-heading" data-toggle='collapse' data-target='#emailComment' onclick='toggleChevron(this)'>
            <strong>Комментарий</strong> <i class='icon-chevron-right'></i>
        </div>
        <div id="emailComment" class="collapse" data-parent="#comment-wrapper">
            <textarea class="emailComment"></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
```

JS:

```
function toggleInServ(box){
    var checked = $(box).prop('checked');
    if(checked){
        $('#in-serv-container').css('height', '170px');
    }else{
        $('#in-serv-container').css('height', '0px');
    }
}

function toggleChevron(o){

    var icon = $(o).children('[class*=icon]');

    if(icon.hasClass('icon-chevron-right')){
        icon.removeClass('icon-chevron-right');
        icon.addClass('icon-chevron-down');
    }else{
        icon.removeClass('icon-chevron-down');
        icon.addClass('icon-chevron-right');
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you create a fiddler for your problem

Comment: Can you please be more specific. Describe us what you expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was because of 'bubbling'. I added `e.stopPropoganation()` and it help.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm in the right track at this, you want each dropdown to stay on opened if the checkbox is ticked? What ever is the case here, please provide us with your CSS-styling as well. Would be best if you'd give us [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) of your case.

Changing just the

```
height
```

attribute of your CSS seems like a bad idea. Instead of that, you could try using

```
display: block;
```

and

```
display: none;
```

So it would really be a hidden field before it gets selected. Not the answer to the question itself, but just something to note.